# List K8 deployment based on replica count using kubectl

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a kubernetes deployments under the test-namespace as given below

```
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
test-controller           1/1     1            1           38d
services-controller       1/1     1            1           38d
intimidation-controller   1/1     1            1           38d
Origin-controller         2/2     2            2          38d
```

What command I can use to list only deployments which are having replica count less than 2.
So that if I run that command it should return only below output

```
test-controller          
services-controller       
intimidation-controller
```

I used following command for this , but it didn't help and didn't retun anything

```
 kubectl get deployment   -n test-namespace -o=jsonpath='{.status.Readyreplicas=1}'
```

What Command I could use to fetch only the deployment names with less than two replica count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this ?

```
kubectl get deployments.apps -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{\"\t\"}{.status.replicas}{\"\n\"}{end}" | awk '/1/ {print$1," ",$NF}'
```